# How can i set environment variable for ffmpeg.exe using uwp c# code?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, uwp

set environment variable for **ffmpeg.exe using code in C# UWP**?

Answer (score 0):

Edit Environment Variables Edit on path set path of ffmpeg exe like c:\foldername

and paste ffmpeg.exe file to this folder .
run command prompt write ffmpeg
check output